# Custom validator with dependencies

Tags: php, symfony, service, dependencies, constraints

I tried to create a constraint that check if an email exists in the database.

I have a method in a service that solve my problem. But, my question is, how do to the validateBy method call my service method?

Im reading the official doc, but I dont understand how "hook" my context in the example:

```
services:
     validator.unique.your_validator_name:
     class: Fully\Qualified\Validator\Class\Name
     tags:
         - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: alias_name }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you've to inject your service in your custom validator in order to access the method you want to use.

It's as easy as adding a service reference to your validator as follow,

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class EmailConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    /*
     * @var path_to_your_service/ServiceClass $yourService
     */
    private $yourService;

    public setYourService($instanceOfYourService)
    {
        $this->yourService = $instanceOfYourService;
    }
}
```

Then, in order to fill this reference, you should call the appropriate setter (this may also be done through the constructor) in your validator service definition,

```
services:
     validator.unique.your_validator_name:
     class: Fully\Qualified\Validator\Class\Name
     tags:
         - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: alias_name }
     calls:
         - [setYourService, ["id_of_your_service"]]
```

This allows you to use your service within your custom validator,

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
    $this->yourService->theTargetedMethod(); // with the appropriate parameters
}
```

Also, as you want to check if a given email exists or not in your database, keep in mind that Symfony provides a [UniqueEntity constraint validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) that is used on this purpose. The documentation includes [a relevant example (related to unique email validation)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html).

Comment: Thanks, now i have more idea ^^